# how to append data of row1 on table1 to row2 on table2 and make both filed same using query

Tags: sql

how to append data of  row1 on table1 to  row2 on table2 and make both filed same using query

row1="hii"

row2="Hellow"

then

row1="hii hellow"

row2="hii hellow"

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: i wanted to map 2 table and make them equal, if row1 having some data, i want to preserve data of row1 while coping from row2

Comment: Sorry, but it just does not make any sense.

Comment: i need to append data of 2 field

Comment: Post your table data and expected output .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you're clearly talking about two different tables and so two different updates. Is this remotely close?

```
update table1
set row1 = row1 + ' ' + (select row2 from table2) --where row_id = ??)
--where row_id = ??

update table2
set row2 = (select row1 from table1) --where row_id = ??)
--where row_id = ??
```